# Filtering records from SQLite in android (which have % or _ character)

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to query records which have % and _ in the table.

Unfortunately those 2 special symbols have own behavior in SQLite.

Rest of special symbols can able to queried from DB.

Please help me solve this issue.

@CL : I am using getActivity().getContentResolver().query() for retrieving the data. Not at all raw queries. How to pass the ESCAPE input

Comment: @CL : I am using getActivity().getContentResolver().query() for retrieving the data. Not at all raw queries. How to pass the ESCAPE input

Comment: This is not what you asked, and in any case, the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) shows it.

Comment: @CL : Thanks for the response. Issue was identified and fixed.